# SQL Server update set case when

Tags: sql-server

I want to fill the column `[Recipient on contract]` of my table `[DB].[dbo].[Check_Result]` using `update` and some `case when` conditions.
The error seems to be located near the `Set [Recipient on contract] =` statement.

This is the following error message I get when running the query:
"Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

I call your attention specifically on the SET [column] = multiple rows part of the query.

```
 --add an empty column
Alter table [DB].[dbo].[Check_Result]
add [Recipient on contract] varchar(200)

--Check_rules
update [DB].[dbo].[Check_Result]
    Set [Recipient on contract] =
    case when 'Personne morale' in(select [Bénéficiaire]
                                   from [DB_SANOFI].[dbo].All_Contracts$) then 
        case when (select [Organisme]
                   from [DB_SANOFI].[dbo].All_Contracts$) is not null then (select substring(Organisme, 1 ,PATINDEX('%(%', Organisme)-1) from All_Contracts$)
             else (select substring([Professionnel de santé], 1 ,PATINDEX('%/%', [Professionnel de santé])-1) from All_Contracts$)
             end
    else
        case when (select [Professionnel de santé]
                   from [DB_SANOFI].[dbo].All_Contracts$) is not null then (select substring([Professionnel de santé], 1 ,PATINDEX('%/%', [Professionnel de santé])-1) from All_Contracts$)
             else (select substring(Organisme, 1 ,PATINDEX('%(%', Organisme)-1) from All_Contracts$)
             end
    end;
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message you provided explains the exact problem you are having. The query you are using to select the value to place into `[Recipient on contract]` is returning more than one value. You need to narrow the scope of your sub query to return only a single record.

It could be any one of the sub-queries:

```
select substring(Organisme, 1 ,PATINDEX('%(%', Organisme)-1) from All_Contracts$

select substring([Professionnel de santé], 1 ,PATINDEX('%/%', [Professionnel de santé])-1) from All_Contracts$

select substring([Professionnel de santé], 1 ,PATINDEX('%/%', [Professionnel de santé])-1) from All_Contracts$

select substring(Organisme, 1 ,PATINDEX('%(%', Organisme)-1) from All_Contracts$
```

Try running each of those and figure out which one (most likely all of them as you aren't limiting any of them with a `WHERE` clause) is giving you more than one result.

Comment: All of those subqueries are giving a single column which is the same format as the column I am trying to update [Recipient on contract].

Comment: A single column, yes, but multiple rows.

Comment: Should I use a JOIN statement before the SET?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer but will help you solve your own problem. Let's first simplify your query to a single case:

```
update [DB].[dbo].[Check_Result]
    Set [Recipient on contract] =
        (select substring([Professionnel de santé], 1 ,
           PATINDEX('%/%', [Professionnel de santé])-1) 
           from All_Contracts$)
```

Now look closely. The subquery will return a value for EVERY ROW in All_Contracts$. You did not correlate that subquery with the table in the outer (update) statement so the engine gladly generates the resultset of your subquery and then attempts to assign many (even if only 2) rows to the column in each and every row of the Check_Result table. It can't do that so you get an error.

So the key is to correlate all these subqueries. To do that correctly, one needs to understand the relationships between the tables you reference (and perhaps others you left out by accident or error). If you can provide that information, someone might be able to help.

Note that this is rather complicated sql - certainly not something for a beginner. Have you considered asking local resources at your giant consulting firm for help?

Side note. You are referencing tables in different databases. You increase the risk of errors by not using 3 part names for **all** tables. You have at least 2 references to All_Contracts$ that have neither database nor schema. In addition, much of your case conditions seem to be logically incorrect. Those will not generate syntax or runtime errors but they will probably not produce correct results. Again - you will benefit greatly if you can get help from your co-workers.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I might need to use some joins to link the rows between tables?
People are very busy here and thus difficult to ask them some help

Comment: " _You did not correlate that subquery with the table in the outer (update) statement_ "